# CABasicAnimation maintain a constant speed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uilabel

I am trying to create a simple animation with CABasicAnimation that will always hold a constant speed, even if the distance the animation must travel is never the same. Here is my code so far, it is scrolling a label that will always vary in size, but cannot yet hold a constant speed. Help is much appreciated.

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.speed = 1.0f;

NSNumber *fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.mainLabel.frame.origin.x];
NSNumber *toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-self.mainLabel.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.height];
theAnimation.fromValue = fromValue;
theAnimation.toValue = toValue;
//theAnimation.duration = toValue.floatValue - fromValue.floatValue;//Not right.
theAnimation.repeatCount = 999;
theAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
[mainLabel.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try add:

```
 theAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
```

in example after

```
 theAnimation.speed = 1.0f;
```

?

This function set linear sped of animation.

Comment: Yes i tried it, but the animation is already linear. The issue is that different label sizes, yield different animation speeds. It will scroll at a constant rate, but when the label size changes it will scroll at a different constant rate. This is because the animation either has more or less distance to cover. This is when the animation is started over, with a different label + size.

Comment: may be you need use for this keyframe animation, so set "check points" in which you will change coefficients for saving persistent animation.  This good example of such animation (only example).

Comment: Hmmm maybe that is the case but I think I may have actually got it work with this `theAnimation.duration = (fromValue.floatValue - toValue.floatValue)/440;`

Comment: Look, if you apply this animation for different labels with different size you need line up  different rates. And then check and set this rates depending on to which label apply. So for one label value of theAnimation.duration is normal, but for another label in example this too small or large.